# Netflix Auto-Logout for obsessed girlfriend

Tags: python

background story my girlfriend watches about 12 TV-Show episodes everyday and i keep telling her it's not good. I have made this script that kicks her out of my account for **20 times** in an hour.

However, After 20 logouts it gives out a **Technical difficulties error** and i want to improve as to why?

```
import sched, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


def excf(): 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/anonymous/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
    driver.get('https://www.netflix.com/ManageDevices');

    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("id_userLoginId")
    inputElement.send_keys('email_netflix')

    inputElementP = driver.find_element_by_id("id_password")
    inputElementP.send_keys('pass_netflix')
    inputElementP.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


    time.sleep(3)

    python_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Sign Out"]')
    python_button.click()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.quit()



s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def logout(sc): 
    print("Logging out")
    excf()
    
    s.enter(60, 1, logout, (sc,))

s.enter(60, 1, logout, (s,))
s.run()
```

Comment: "Technical difficulties error" is that an error thrown by the code or by Netflix?

Comment: @Mast by Netflix

Comment: Seems by-design then. Netflix detects something is messing with the application. Which is correct.

Comment: Anyway, if your question is to fix this behaviour, that's not something we can help with. If the Netflix behaviour is acceptable, we can help polish your code. Please clarify.

Comment: @Mast yes— Id be much appreciated to see your answers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not asking for opinions on and advice for the way the code is written. It is a complaint about the design of a net service rather than a programming question, so it won't fit stack**overflow**.

Comment: @greybeard hello— I did not ask this question on stackoverflow.. this is code review where we ask for opinions on a code and expect someone to polish it, I may be doing something wrong but I don’t know so that’s why I ask here so everyone including the experts have a look.